# How to get the web highlight color programatically?

Tags: javascript, dart, web, colors, highlight

I want to get the highlight color of a div, but programatically. Here's what I tryied:

```
    final e = html.document.getElementById("body");
    e?.style?.backgroundColor = "highlight";
    print(e?.style?.backgroundColor);
```

It returns `highlight`, but I'd like to have its hex or rgb code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to return the RGB value which is what browsers return regardless of format that developer used to set color.

Then you can parse the RGB to hex if needed

```js
const bod = document.body
bod.style.backgroundColor = 'highlight'

console.log(getComputedStyle(bod).backgroundColor)
```